# Anybody succeed in making DID Registration on test (Decentralized Identity Microsoft SDK)?

Tags: decentralized-identity

I was able to register DID on ion-test, but the instructions on test seem weird https://didproject.azurewebsites.net/docs/registration-test.html 
.pem files are generated but then the example uses .kwt, also the output of the make-jws.js is not a compact jwt, so the registration curl is not working

Anyone able to register on test and can provide directions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrea, we're working on a refresh of that documentation, which is a bit out of date. I'd stay tuned for new instructions over the next month or so. Feel free to reach out if you want to discuss further. Thanks for trying things out!

Comment: Thank you - looking forward to it. Do you also plan to expand the claims management part? It would be interesting to have a working scenario from DID registration to claim management. Thank you. Andrea